# How to add a value to this SQL statement in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

I need to add 'P06' to the case where the subquery is selecting RPCODE. I'm still learning about SQL so I'm still not an expert at subqueries so I'm not exactly sure how to add a value to the statement.

My first solution was just to add OR 'P06' after 'P01', but that doesn't seem right.

```
               CASE WHEN (SELECT RPCODE FROM AGQA.QAB2010
                 WHERE  INDATE || INTIME = ( SELECT MAX(INDATE||INTIME) FROM AGQA.QAB2010 WHERE RTAG  IN (SELECT TAG FROM TAGDATA) )
                  AND RTAG  IN (SELECT TAG FROM TAGDATA) ORDER BY RPDATE DESC, SER DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) = 'P01'  THEN  'N' ELSE 'C' END
        ELSE 'R' END, 'S' )  AS TTYPE
```

Right now, when the RPCODE is 'P01', the TTYPE shows as 'N'. I need to add 'P06' so that the TTYPE will show as 'N' for RPCODE 'P06' as well

Comment: Change the `= 'P01'` to ` IN `('P01', 'P06')`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob Wilson commented...

> Change the `= 'P01'` to `IN ('P01', 'P06')`

However, while the statement may work for you, performance over a dataset of any decent size is probably going to suck.

The number of sub-select's and `fetch first row` are red flags to my eye.

With a background in RPG development on Db2 for i, the statement looks like many I've seen from RPG programmers used to working with data 1 record at a time rather than working with sets of data.

But the same "row by agonizing row" (RBAR as coined by Jeff Moden of SqlServerCentral.com) processing can be seen in SQL from developers on any platform and from any background.

Unfortunately, moving to a set base process isn't a quick fix for non-trivial statements.  The complete statement and detailed information about the data and the table design is needed.

Comment: Thank you! The code was written previously by someone else. I'm in charge of editing the code as needs arise. There are a lot of sub-selects used throughout the entire database, which makes it hard for me to edit the code, since I still do not fully understand sub-queries.